# WordPress - Blue Bar Showing in Header

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am playing around with a responsive wordpress theme based on the skeleton and have hit an annoying problem. A thin blue horizontal bar has appeared at the top of the screen, it can't be anymore than about 15-18px height and has absolute positioning because it stay at the top of the page even when you scroll down. I've used both chrome and firefox (with firebug) to find out where it has come from but to no avail, it's not showing in the css or the source code. Has anyone else experienced this or know why this is happening?

N.B. It appears in all browsers IE, Chrome & FF.
URL: http://www.produceme.co.nz/

[image]

Comment: It's nothing to do with the front-end admin panel is it?  Try logging out the backend to see if it goes away.

Comment: I've logged out of the backend and completely clear my cache. But the blue bar still shows?

Comment: I'm assuming you must have it on localhost or you'd have given a link.  Throw it up online, someone will get it quickly I'm sure (I'm off to bed but good luck!)

Comment: You can find out with chrome inspector, if you need real time help provide the website address...

Comment: Yeah it's running on localhost at the moment. I'll throw it up online, and provide a link.

Comment: Added a live link to the website now. http://www.produceme.co.nz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue background you are seeing is from your css, You probably have this:

```
background:#fcfcfc url(.../images/border_top.png)
```

in your body style, so just find it and remove it, and you're good to go.

Comment: No CSS styles with those attributes.

Comment: This is correct, I've just expanded the answer with where it's actually located.

Comment: @AquilaSolutions: The fact that it shows get_styles in your url shows that it is styled dynamically, so you should go to the theme options and look for it, if it doesn't work, then try overriding it in your `style.css` like this: `body{ background: none }`

Comment: body{ background: none; } - Solved the issue. Thanks @ChibuezeOpata

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `http://www.produceme.co.nz/?get_styles=css` on line 1.

You have the following defined

```
body
{
    background: #fcfcfc url(http://www.produceme.co.nz/wp-content/themes/skeleton/images/border_top.png) repeat-x top center fixed;
    color: #444444;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

The background URL is the part that is adding it. Delete that value and it'll fix it for you.

Comment: The background style attribute you mention does not seem to be showing in my stylesheets, so I added a new attribute 'background: none;' and this has worked. Issue solved.